# Android Studio XML reformat code ignores xmlns:.* attributes

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-studio-2.0, reformatting

Android Studio's reformat code ignores the first 2 Matching rules I've configured, rule for placing xmlns:android attribute as the first attribute and xmlns:.* attributes right below it.

My Matching rules:
[image: Matching rules]

The code after reformatting:
[image: layout.xml]

Are my rules right defined? Is this a bug in Android Studio?

I'm using Android Studio 2.0 beta 5.

Comment: reformatting only deletes the code which is not used....

Comment: @BajiraoShinde Actually it also rearranges the code according to Matching rules in XML code style settings. At least in my Android Studio.

Comment: @BajiraoShinde Are you experiencing the same behavior as me when you perform code rearrangement with the xmlns:android attribute at the end of tag?

Comment: yes thats why I said that.... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've got the answer thanks to my colleague.

1. You have to set ALL the rules as attributes **OR** remove attribute flag in ALL of them.
2. set `.*` as namespace for `xmlns:.*` rules

Example:
[image: Matching rules]